# statsmodels summary to latex

Tags: python, latex, statsmodels

I'm a newbie to latex and I want to import a [statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/)(python-package) summary to my report in latex. I found that it's possible to transform a summary into a latex tabular with the following method: [latex_as_tabular](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.iolib.table.SimpleTable.as_latex_tabular.html?highlight=as_latex_tabular#statsmodels.iolib.table.SimpleTable.as_latex_tabular). Until now everything is working. Now I have to store the tabular, but I don't really understand how this works.

I suppose I have to use the following commands:

```
x_values=sm.add_constant(x_values)
model=sm.OLS(y_values, x_values)
results=model.fit()
tbl=results.summary(xname=['b,'a'],yname='y')
with open('c:/temp/temp.tex','w') as fh:
    fh.write( tbl.as_latex_tabular() )
```

this code doesn't work until now. most of the times the console gives the error: tex-file doesn't exists or not permitted in this map. I don't really understand what I have to do here. Could someone please help me with this ?

Comment: Please consider adding the error stacktrace to your question to make it easier for others with a similar problem to find your question.

Comment: There's an error in the example code: A `'` is missing to close character `b`. Plus I recommend to code according to PEP8, in particular having spaces around operators.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That seems to be a misunderstanding. You can either convert a whole summary into latex via [`summary.as_latex()`](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.iolib.summary.Summary.as_latex.html#statsmodels.iolib.summary.Summary.as_latex) or convert its tables one by one by calling [`table.as_latex_tabular()`](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.iolib.table.SimpleTable.as_latex_tabular.html) for each table.

The following example code is taken from `statsmodels` documentation. Note that you cannot call `as_latex_tabular` on a `summary` object.

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

nsample = 100
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
X = np.column_stack((x, x**2))
beta = np.array([1, 0.1, 10])
e = np.random.normal(size=nsample)

X = sm.add_constant(X)
y = np.dot(X, beta) + e

model = sm.OLS(y, X)
results = model.fit()

# do either
print(results.summary().as_latex())

# alternatively
for table in results.summary().tables:
    print(table.as_latex_tabular())
```

Comment: Ok you're right. But it's still not clear for me how it's possible to insert   it into a tex-file. the summery is converted into latex string and after that ?

Comment: After that you have a string with latex code - no more, no less. What you do with that string is up to you.
You could e.g. write that string into a file and include this file in one of your latex documents.