# Printing model summary with number (index)

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I wonder if there is away when you call ***model.summary()*** it display it in such away there is an index for for each layer. For example like this:

```
1 input_image (InputLayer)       [(None, 128, 128, 3  0           []                               
                                )]                                                                
                                                                                                  
2 conv1_pad (ZeroPadding2D)      (None, 134, 134, 3)  0           ['input_image[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
3 conv1_conv (Conv2D)            (None, 64, 64, 64)   9472        ['conv1_pad[0][0]']
```

Comment: I can see the reason for asking but right now you need to get the middle layer by their name by visualizing the summary. But I agree that it would be nice to print the index value with `model.summary`. I think you should raise a feature request on repo.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65978432/9215780

Answer (score 0):

I think your model has been saved as a single layer, try:

**model.layers[1].summary()**